# Exchange Web Services from SharePoint 2007.. which DLL?

Tags: deployment, dll, sharepoint-2007, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

MOSS 2007 is .net 2.0.. I found this DLL Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll and moved it to my bin and added  this to web.config

SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices" TypeName="*" Safe="True"

But can't seem to introduce it into SharePoint 2007 without get this error:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that DLL, use the EWS Managed API. It's far simpler to use than native web services.

EWS Managed API - Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480
EWS Managed API - SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx